# I need to concatenate the output of the current iteration to the last one in while loop

Tags: python

I need to concatenate the output of the current iteration in while loop to the last one as I am calculating the function Cal_RSRP (which is a function that takes 2 inputs and return a dataframe of one column as an output) for each sector through the function choosing_sec and I need to concatenate the results of each iteration from Cal_RSRP function in one output dataframe here is the code

```
number_sectors = 2
n = 1
while(n<=number_sectors):
    sector = choosing_sec(n)
    antenna = sector[0]
    azimuth = sector[1]
    tilt =  sector[2]
    ACP_RSRP = cal_RSRP(250,30)
    if n > 1:
        ACP_RSRP = np.concatenate((ACP_RSRP),  axis=1)
    n = n+1
```

and this error occurs:

```
zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the result of the current iteration in a temporary variable. In this case: temp. Also np.concatenate() takes a list or a tuple of arrays that should be concatenated. In your code, you only give one parameter. See below.

```
number_sectors = 2
n = 1
while(n<=number_sectors):
    sector = choosing_sec(n)
    antenna = sector[0]
    azimuth = sector[1]
    tilt =  sector[2]
    temp = cal_RSRP(250,30)
    if n > 1:
        ACP_RSRP = np.concatenate((ACP_RSRP, temp),  axis=1)
    n = n+1
```

Comment: I am still facing this error:
'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: ACP_RSRP = np.concatenate((ACP_RSRP, temp),  axis=1)

Comment: The concatenation part is correct. The error is coming from the variable temp which uses the function cal_RSRP(250,30). You have to look into your cal_RSRP function to find the error. I can't help you with that, because I do not know what your cal_RSRP function does.